# How to make this conversion more effective?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bioinformatics

I'm working on a python vcf to EIGENSTRAT format converter. I have a code, that works perfectly, but it's really slow, so i can't really use it during the project. I read genotype data from vcf.gz and convert it to .geno format with this code.

```
import allel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

callset = allel.read_vcf("/DATABASES/1KGphase3VCF/ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502/ALL.chr22.phase3_shapeit2_mvncall_integrated_v5b.20130502.genotypes.vcf.gz")

geno = (callset['calldata/GT'])
index = list(callset['variants/POS'])
samples = list(callset['samples'])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=samples)
# df["Index"] = index
# df = df.set_index('Index')
geno_list = []
for i in range(0, len(geno[:, 0])):
    for k in range(0, len(geno[1, :])):
        if geno[i, k, 0] == 0 and geno[i, k, 1] == 0:
            geno_list.append(2)
        elif geno[i, k, 0] == 1 and geno[i, k, 1] == 0 or geno[i, k, 0] == 0 and geno[i, k, 1] == 1:
            geno_list.append(1)
        elif geno[i, k, 0] == 1 and geno[i, k, 1] == 1:
            geno_list.append(0)
        else:
            geno_list.append(9)
    df.loc[i] = geno_list
    geno_list = []

numpy_array = df.to_numpy()
NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = -1  # on linux -2 on Windows?
with open('test_chr22.geno', 'wb') as fout:  # Note 'wb' instead of 'w'
    np.savetxt(fout, numpy_array, delimiter="", fmt='%d')
    fout.seek(NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES, 2)
    fout.truncate()
```

Is there a way to this code to be faster? This vcf.gz tooks around 10-12 hours to convert, and this is the smallest one. The calldata/GT is a 1.5 million x 2500 x 2 array.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to speed up your code and simplify some calculations:

```py
import allel
# just in time compilation for numpy calculations
# import numba as nb 
import numpy as np
# pandas import completely unnecessary -> numpy is sufficient


# @nb.njit
def create_mat(geno):
    # create matrix as np.uint8 (1 byte) instead of list of python integers (8 byte)
    # also no need to dynamically resize / increase list size
    geno_mat = np.zeros((len(geno[:, 0]), len(geno[1, :])), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    for i in np.arange(len(geno[:, 0])):
        for k in np.arange(len(geno[1, :])):
            g = geno[i, k]

            # nested ifs to avoid duplicate comparisons
            if g[0] == 0:
                if g[1] == 0:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 2
                elif g[1] == 1:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 1
                else:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 9
            elif g[0] == 1:
                if g[1] == 0:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 1
                elif g[1] == 1:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 0
                else:
                    geno_mat[i, k] = 9
            else:
                geno_mat[i, k] = 9
    return geno_mat
    

# you really only need to read the "calldata/GT" fields - everything else was never used
# created a subset of the data using just the first 1000 columns
geno = allel.read_vcf("genomes_first_1000.vcf", fields=("calldata/GT",))["calldata/GT"]
mat = create_mat(geno)
```

Timings tested:

```py
In [7]: %timeit original(geno)
10.8 s ± 154 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [10]: %timeit optimized(geno)
5.8 s ± 49.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [19]: %timeit optimized_numba(geno)
6.65 ms ± 43.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

We can see a speedup of almost 2 for just rewriting code with `numpy`. Including `numba`s jit-compilation we can achieve a speedup of ~1,500.